# Macro in Delmia

Tags: vba, catia

I am programming some VBA macros in Delmia with interface to make easier the life of the user.

I know, in Delmia, there is the option to "Start Recording" macro, then I can make some operation in delmia and see the code generated by these operations. But when I click, by example, on "Restore initial state". There is no code generate.

Is someone know where I can find a list of the command in VBA to call some delmia's function in my macro.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for the Catia automation APIs but it can be hard to find. CAA/RADE comes with the documentation for both the C++ APIs and the automation APIs.

Another trick is to use the VBA object browser.

unfortunately, I can't find the documentation on the 3DS website any more, I wish they would do a better job keeping their documentation posted :(